# R: plot multiple lines in different colours from subset of database

Tags: r, plot, colors

I've created a database with six different countries and multiple GDP and inequality measures.

For starters, I want to plot the GDP growth of the countries in one plot. This works out perfectly fine:

```
plot(my_six_countries$Year, my_six_countries$GDP.growth.rate, main = "Development of GDP growth", xlab = "Year", ylab = "GDP growth", type = "l", col = 600)
```

However, I want the lines for the different countries to be displayed in different colours and not just 600. I virtually spend the whole day on this super nooby problem and I've tried all sort of things from creating a colour vector over subsetting manually to playing with ggplot - but I'm really stuck.

Any idea how the lines could be displayed in different colours?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you should include a reproducible example

Comment: You can use `ggplot(my_six_countries, aes(x = Year, y = GDP.growth.rate, col = whatever_country_name_variable_is) + geom_line()`

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that I ended up using a way less elegant method - but it worked.

Firstly, I subsetted my countries.

```
c1 <- subset(countries,countries$Country=="c1")
c2 <- subset(countries,countries$Country=="c2")
c3 <- subset(countries,countries$Country=="c3")
```

Secondly, I plotted the lines one by one.

```
plot(c1$Year, c1$GDP, type = "l", bty="l", col="brown")
lines(c2$Year, c2$GDP, col="cornflowerblue")
lines(c3$Year, c3$GDP, col="darkblue")
```